# Put everything into sas sql

Tags: sas

I have two codes one proc sql and another proc and datastep. Both are interlinked datasets.

Below is the proc sql lines.

```
 create table new as select a.id,a.alid,b.pdate from tb a inner join 
tb1 act on a.aid =act.aid left join tb2 as b on (r.alid=a.alid) where 
a.did in (15,45); quit;
```

Below is the proc and datasteps created from above datatset new.

```
    proc sort data = new uodupkey;
    by alid;

   data new1;
   set new;
   format ddate date9.
   dat1=datepart(today);
   datno=input(number,20.);
   key=_n_;
   rename alid blid;
   run;

   proc sort data=new1 nodupkey;
   by datno dat1;
   run;
```

I need to put  everything into single proc sql step.

Comment: Do you really need to generate the KEY variable using the order of the records?  You could try using the unsupported `monotonic()` function.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask], and modify your question to include the code you have written to attempt to solve this problem, and/or to focus your question on the specific issue you're having trouble with, rather than asking us to write code for you.

Comment: Can you explain why you are currently use PROC SORT with NODUPKEY option?  Do you have multiple observations per ALID value? What is the criteria for picking just one of them?

Comment: Can you explain your question better? Also include some example input and output data to demonstrate the problem you are trying to solve. Note that your posted code has typos and that the SQL code and data and proc steps do not appear to be referring to the same tables since the variable names are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

You mention two data steps but I only see one.

Anyway, your data step and proc sort can indeed be written in one sql query (which you can then insert in your `proc sql`):

```
proc sql;
  create table new1 as
  select id
        ,alid as blid
        ,pdate
        ,datepart(today) as dat1
        ,input(number,20.) as datno
        ,monotonic() as key
  from new1
  group by datno, dat1
  having key=min(key)
  ;
quit;
```

One remark though. Your data step expects variables called `ddate`,`today` and `number` in your input dataset `new`. If that dataset is supposed to be the result of your first sql query, then those variables don't exist and their values along with those of `dat1` and `datno` in `new1` will always be missing.
Also I assume you misspelled `nodupkey` on your `proc sort`.

EDIT: or, to have it all in the same **query** (if that's what you meant with "the same proc sql"):

```
proc sql;
  create table new1 as
  select id
        ,alid as blid
        ,pdate
        ,datepart(today) as dat1
        ,input(number,20.) as datno
        ,monotonic() as key
  from (
        select a.id,a.alid,b.pdate
        from tb a
        inner join tb1 act
          on a.aid =act.aid
        left join tb2 as b
          on (r.alid=a.alid)
        where a.did in (15,45)
        )
  group by datno, dat1
  having key=min(key)
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: I would strongly discourage using `MONOTONIC()` with `group by`, this is exactly where it can behave differently than expected.

Comment: In fact I'm quite sure the `key` here would not be identical to the `key` from the datastep, given it's sorted by `alid` there while here it will act as if it were sorted by `datno, dat1` when calculating monotonic.

Comment: why  are we using groupby here? Could you please explain the code. I have two proc sort step

Comment: @Joe, as Tom pointed out in his comment above, the asker is using `proc sort nodupkey` with no apparent criteria for keeping one 'dup' record over other ones. Therefore the resulting behavior of `monotonic()` with `group by` doesn't seem to matter much.

Comment: @suresh999, we use `group by` here to reproduce a behavior similar to the `nodupkey` option on your `proc sort`.

Comment: @user2877959 The fact that the user doesn't mention a particular reason doesn't mean that it won't have a different result, and that could be a harmful result.  The user may not be familiar with the rationale, or may not be showing all of the code that explains it.  `PROC SORT NODUPKEY` does remove records in a repeatable fashion, after all.